# Using lapply correctly

Tags: r, lapply, ibrokers, tws

I'm working with the TWS API and it's not working for me.  I got it close to doing what I want to do, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to use the lapply function correctly.

Here's what I got to work currently:

```
library("IBrokers")
tws <- twsConnect()
tickers <- c("AAPL","YHOO")
reqMktData(tws, lapply(tickers, twsSTK), tickGenerics="", snapshot=T)
twsDisconnect(tws)
```

I would like to make specifications to the twsSTK in the above.  Without using lapply, a single

```
library("IBrokers")
tws <- twsConnect()
reqMktData(tws, twsSTK("AAPL", exch = "ISLAND", currency = "USD"), tickGenerics="", snapshot=T)
twsDisconnect(tws)
```

However, I am having trouble trying to adequately use lapply in this case.

Does anyone know how to deal with lapply here?

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation on lapply incorrectly.  See attached for my solution.

```
library("IBrokers")
tws <- twsConnect()
tickers <- c("AAPL","YHOO","MSFT","GLD")
reqMktData(tws, lapply(tickers, twsSTK, exch = "ISLAND", currency = "USD"), tickGenerics="", snapshot=T)
twsDisconnect(tws)
```